# Display minutes in the "answered X hours ago" item

Tags: support, answers, sorting, timestamps

If I get more than one correct answer, I want to accept the earlier one. When both answers are posted at the same hour, the site displays something like "answered 2 hours ago." I have no way to determine which answer came first.

I also don't know the cut off of when the number of minutes shows up. It seems I have to wait for maybe a day.

So, instead of "answered 2 hours ago," I suggest we display "answered 2 hours *x* minutes" ago.

Answer (score 15):

Hover the mouse pointer over the "... X hours ago" text and it will tell you the exact date and time.

Comment: +1 - Not only is your answer better than mine, you did it 14 seconds sooner!

Comment: @Adam: Hopefully the OP takes my advice so he can tell for sure that I answered sooner! ;)

Comment: That's alright, I found a fatal flaw in your method, and pretended you were merely assisting me at the same time.  Take that!

Comment: We're just so in sync, it's like we finish each others...

Comment: ...chicken sandwiches.

Comment: You just ruined what could have been a beautiful moment... and the correct answer was "waffles", by the way.

Comment: ...you...you're right.  I'll go pack up my things and go ... quietly ... *sobs* ... what we had was beautiful ... *sniffle* ... while it lasted...

Comment: This is easy to do for one answer. This is annoying to do for multiple answers.

Answer (score 8):

To accept the earliest answer, just click the Newest tab!

[image]

Comment: Selecting "oldest" would be better, since it would put the first one at the very top of the list.

Comment: I gave you the upvote, but you need freehand circles around these parts.

Comment: Hey now!  We were here first.  People think they can bust in on us just because their answer is better... *grumble grumble grumble* (+1)

Comment: @Cigs: Exactly, there's just *no way* we can tell what part of the image he might be referring to!

Answer (score 6):

Check out the direct link just below the answer.  The end of the link is the post number of the answer, and the earlier answer will have a lower number.

As demonstrated by my assistant gnovice and I, even HH:MM wouldn't be enough - you'd also need SS, which would be too large for the field.  Hovering over the time gives you seconds resolution, but for the occasional posted-in-the-same-second (it happens on SO more often than I expected) you'll need to check out the post ID, given at the end of the direct link.

Comment: +1: I imagine the highly-active tags often have posts within the same second.

Comment: With over 1,500 questions/answers posted per hour during the busy times it's guaranteed.