# Is it possible to know the date and time of an answer (and not just "n days ago")?

Tags: support, timestamps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display minutes in the “answered X hours ago” item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30108/display-minutes-in-the-answered-x-hours-ago-item)

I have a question with two answers that are almost equal:

[Idiomatic C++ for remove_if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263044/idiomatic-c-for-remove-if/6263192#6263192)

[Idiomatic C++ for remove_if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263044/idiomatic-c-for-remove-if/6263182#6263182)

I would like to accept the oldest one but I can not see the date and time because it is too early and I just get "answered 2 days ago".

How many day must I wait in order to get an absolute date and time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the mouse over the relative time and wait for the tooltip.

Comment: Thank you. It was so simple... I did not thought about.